# Using tidyverse %>% pipe with Dates and format(); how to prevent gobbledygook characters?

Tags: r, pipe, tidyverse

I have a tibble with a column formatted as Dates. For the purposes of the question, I'll generate similar data (the real data is much larger!):

```
> dates = tribble(~YrMon, "2011-01-01", "2011-02-01", "2011-03-01", "2011-04-01") 
              %>% mutate(YrMon = as.Date(YrMon))
> dates
# A tibble: 4 x 1
  YrMon     
  <date>    
1 2011-01-01
2 2011-02-01
3 2011-03-01
4 2011-04-01
```

I want to isolate just the months. When I extract the months without using a pipe it works as expected:

```
> format(dates$YrMon, "%m")
[1] "01" "02" "03" "04"
```

However, when I use a tidyverse pipe to do what I think should be the same thing, I get gobbledygook (I assume this is some sort of formatting of the tibble being returned):

```
> dates %>% format(.$YrMon, "%m")
[1] "\033[38;5;246m# A tibble: 4 x 1\033[39m"          
[2] "  YrMon     "                                     
[3] "  \033[3m\033[38;5;246m<date>\033[39m\033[23m    "
[4] "\033[38;5;250m1\033[39m 2011-01-01"               
[5] "\033[38;5;250m2\033[39m 2011-02-01"               
[6] "\033[38;5;250m3\033[39m 2011-03-01"               
[7] "\033[38;5;250m4\033[39m 2011-04-01"
```

What's going on and is there a way to get the expected answers using a %>% pipe?

Comment: What is gobbledygook? Does it have a simpler term? Also why not put everything in mutate or pull and format? or lubridate's month? Here's something with `pull`:`dates %>% 
  pull(YrMon) %>% 
   format(., "%m")` but I'd go with `month`.

Comment: Or Try `dates$YrMon %>% format(., "%m") `

Comment: or `dates %>% with(., format(YrMon, "%m"))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve the desired output in a couple of ways. We can use `pull` to extract our target column and deal with that as follows:

```
dates %>% pull(YrMon) %>% format(., "%m")
[1] "01" "02" "03" "04"
```

Alternatively, we can simply use `mutate` as follows:

```
dates %>% 
 mutate(YrMon = format(YrMon, "%m"))
# A tibble: 4 x 1
  YrMon
  <chr>
1 01   
2 02   
3 03   
4 04
```

One can also get the month with `lubridate`'s `month`(returns an integer):

```
dates %>% 
   mutate(YrMon = month(YrMon))
# A tibble: 4 x 1
  YrMon
  <int>
1     1
2     2
3     3
4     4
```

With `map`(gives us a list, use `map_*` to override):

```
dates %>% 
   map(.,format,"%m")
$YrMon
[1] "01" "02" "03" "04"
```

Without using the pipe, one can simply do:

```
with(dates, format(YrMon, "%m"))
[1] "01" "02" "03" "04"
```

Comment: Thanks @NelsonGon. First mutate answer was especially helpful - I'm not sure why I didn't try the obvious!

Answer (score 3):

You don't want dot automatically inserted so use this:

```
dates %>% { format(.$YrMon, "%m") }
## [1] "01" "02" "03" "04"
```

or use the magrittr `%$%` pipe:

```
library(magrittr)
dates %$% format(YrMon, "%m")
## [1] "01" "02" "03" "04"
```

This would also work:

```
dates %>% with(format(YrMon, "%m"))
## [1] "01" "02" "03" "04"
```

Comment: Thanks! Your answers work and I appreciate it. I gave the check to @NelsonGon for the mutate answer. No offense intended!